# Installing Jenkins as a windows service

Tags: jenkins, windows-services

At first, I have installed Jenkins using Tomcat.Now I have changed it as windows service. But now am facing issues while copy/paste the files (like permission issue) though am having administrator access in the system & this makes the job to fail.Is this because of installing Jenkins as a windows service?

Comment: Go to Control Panel - Administrative tools -> Services and find Jenkins service. Open properties and check under which account the service runs. Change it to your local administrator user if needed (but note that if you change the password for the account, you'll need to update it there also)

Comment: I have tried this option too. while copying files from C drive to some other location via "Execute Windows batch command", am getting permission denied issue. But am able to copy the files via command prompt using same command.

Comment: Apart from this permission issue, will there any difference because of running Jenkins as Service than in Tomcat container?